# Getting a line graph to begin at the Y-axis?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Really simple question that's driving me nuts for a while. How do I get my line graph in Google Sheets to begin at the Y axis - i.e. so there isn't a gap before the January 2020 date?

I've been looking for a while and can't find the answer.

[image]

**Update**Here's a sample of the data:

[image]

Comment: Can you share some sample data ? it'll be easier for us try to help you, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good chance the data in the horizontal axis are not well formated, especially when it comes to dates.

1. If datas inside the horizontal axis are texts (ex : `'Feb 2020` instead of `Feb 2020`)
   -> try to check `Maximise` inside the chart editor 
   [image]
2. If the datas are the `date` type of format

   - You can try to refactor theses dates with the first day of each month (with something like `=eomonth(startdate , 1)-1`
   - Or check the number of gridlines for the horizontal axis.   [image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I've updated with a sample of the data. I couldn't get either of the solutions above to work. The maximise still left the gap. There was no horizontal gridline option. 

Not sure exactly how to use the eomonth code. I suspect the problem is these are just text dates. But It has to show only the month and not the first of the month - as that would be misleading.

Comment: It only show the month (`Jan 2020`), but as Sheet recognize it as a a date it's a specific day like `01/01/2020` if you check the cell. In other words, it may display `Jan 2020`, but the cell value is a number like 4860 with a date format.

Comment: Ok, so what do I need to do to fix it? It's just text data at the moment :-)

Comment: I tried changing the formatting to dates, but now it's adding the same month in their twice - which makes no real sense: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oenp9gpjb1u2cl9/Screenshot%202020-04-29%2012.11.51.png?dl=0

Comment: Be sure to have some coherent ratios between starting vs ending date and add as much gridlines as you need. Can you share some sample data ? (or a copy of the sheet, can't do much with screenshots)

Comment: How do you have coherent ratios between starting vs. ending date? I'm not sure what you mean from a practical sense. How do I do that when I have 4 months here? Created a duplicate sheet here -> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HMg6Omsk04Z7czhFT5BiN64lREcax5XndQy2ACjBTE8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ahh, I'm with you now. I set the same number of horizontal gridlines as months in the chart and that worked. Thanks :-)

Comment: Cool, you can accept the answer :)

Comment: happy too! How do I do that? Can't see an option here...